# Laravel 8 Unit Test

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am new to Unit Testing. The application has `helpers` (`App\Helpers\Helper`, `'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class` added to the aliases in the `config`).

For tests, it is necessary to use the functionality of the helpers, since authorization goes through another service, and I send all requests there from the helpers.

Test code itself:

```php
class ParticipantsTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_createParticipants()
    {
        $participant = Helper::getRandParticipant();
        $type_participant = Helper::getType(2);
        $token = Helper::chooseToken($type_participant);

        $response = $this->post('/api/participants/create', [
            'token' => Helper::renewToken($participant, $token),
            'type_participant' => $type_participant,
            'callback' => $this->faker->sentence(20),
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);

        $this->assertTrue(count(Task::all()) > 1);
    }
}
```

When passing the test, I get an error:

> Attempt to read property "participant" on `null`

Although when I send a test request to the API using the `getRandParticipnat` method, I get a random participant, and in the tests it is `null`, how I can fix it?

Thanks

**UPD:**

```xml
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> 
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> 
    <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
</php>
```

I think I'm need to reconfig for mysql connection? If I'm do that, can test clear DB with my real data?

Comment: If you are getting `null` from `Helper::getRandParticipant()` and you don't know why, then share that code please... we are not magician to know why. Also, change your IDE to not do `ClassName :: method` or `$ this-> method1-> method2 ($ parameter)`, that is not following PSR and is really hard to read...

Comment: `ClassName :: method or $ this-> method1-> method2 ($ parameter)`  make a stackoverflow

Comment: `public static function getRandParticipnat(){
      $participant = Participant::inRandomOrder()->first('participant');
      return $participant->participant;
    }` If i'm use this function on api, it's work, but didn't work in Unit Test

Comment: So, do you have any data in the database so `Participant::inRandomOrder()` will return a model ? Are you 100% sure you have data ? It seems you don't. Also, I don't see you are using a `factory` to fake `Participant's` data.

Comment: @matiaslauriti, of course I have the data. In the question, I said that. When I use postman to get data from api, from `getRandParticipnat()` function, I get it, but in unit test I have error

Comment: Do you use the same database for your normal usage and for Unit test or do you use 2 different databases for this ?

Comment: After looking at your database, you do not have data in your test database... you are maybe not seeding the database, so it is not an "error", you do not have data on it... How do you add data to that model ? Do you seed ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti of course i didn't seed it :-( Thnx, i'll try to seed sqlite DB.I need to copy my migration from MySQL DB?

Comment: No, you just need to use a trait called `RefreshDatabase` and add do `$this->seed()` if you want your database seeded using Laravel seeders.

Comment: @matiaslauriti i'm add `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;` in head of my test, then in class add `use RefreshDatabase;` then in start of my function add `$this->seed();`, but i'll have same error. Where i'm need to add this? Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

@matiaslaurit I'm use MySQL for API's and config phpunit.xml for Unit Test/
My phpunit.xml:

```
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> 
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> 
    <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
</php>
```

I think I'm need to reconfig for mysql connection? If I'm do that, can test clear DB with my real data?

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question, specially to add this peace of code and all others precision that asked "matiaslaurit". Then, add a comment to tell that you edit your question. But don't self-answer if it doesn't solve your issue ;)